# Media queries - height activating when only width changed

Tags: css, media-queries

I have some media queries like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px){
/**
Piece of code A
*/
}
```

and

```
@media screen and (min-height: 701px) and (max-height: 840px){
/**
Piece of code B
*/
}
```

I test that it all works by resizing the browser.
Piece of code A works i.e it becomes active when screen width is between 701px and 900px.
The problem is that at some point in resizing the browser width, Piece of code B becomes active even though I've not changed the browser height at all!

Comment: you have a link where this can be seen? or better yet.. can you reproduce this in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your code B is unique to this height-specific media query? Can you reproduce this behaviour with a simple mockup, like http://jsfiddle.net/nBkWw/ ?

Comment: Thanks. Played around with it and realised it was something to do with the code that was resizing some elements as well.